# Reference the last row dynamically in a formula Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add the last row in the formula dynamically

I have the formula to copy a range
`=FullOptionLists!$A$1:$Z$275`

To get the last row. I have
`MAX(ROW(A:Z)*(A:Z<>""))`

How to combine them into a single formula
`FullOptionLists'!$A$1:$Z$+MAX(ROW(A:Z)*(A:Z<>""))`

I have also tried `&` in place of `+`

Thanks for any assistaance with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use INDEX as it is non volatile like INDIRECT():

```
=FullOptionLists'!$A$1:INDEX(FullOptionLists'!$Z:$Z,MAX(ROW(A:Z)*(A:Z<>"")))
```

If Z will always end at the bottom of the list this would be quicker.

Numeric in Z:

```
=FullOptionLists'!$A$1:INDEX(FullOptionLists'!$Z:$Z,MATCH(1E+99,FullOptionLists'!$Z:$Z))
```

Text in Z:

```
=FullOptionLists'!$A$1:INDEX(FullOptionLists'!$Z:$Z,MATCH("zzzz",FullOptionLists'!$Z:$Z))
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your data layout, I would just turn your range into a **Table** and use the table reference.  Then you can refer to it merely as

`=myTable`

***Note:***  *A **Table** will automatically adjust its references as you add/remove columns or rows*